# Switching device connections to MCU based on power source

Tags: transistors, relay, switching

Sorry for the vague title, I wasn't quite sure how to word this.

I'm designing a circuit that will have an AVR, an RF module, and a keyboard matrix, powered by battery. The problem is this will use all available GPIO pins on the largest DIP package MCU...

I'd like to also add USB capability (make the device able to be powered by usb, as well as communicate with host instead of using the RF module IF it is plugged in to the usb.) This would also mean I need 2 more pins for D+ and D- which I don't have.

I was thinking I could use a DPDT relay to disconnect the RF module if power comes in from the usb connection, and connect d+ and d- to two of those pins, or if usb is not connected, disconnect d+/d- and connect the RF module.

This seems kind of clunky (no relay pun intended) and I was wondering if something like this could be done with transistors or some strange IC I don't know about.

Is this even doable or am I crazy? Worst case scenario I guess I'll have to learn how to solder those darn surface mount chips with tiny pins that have more GPIO pins... but I'd prefer not to have to do that if at all possible.

Any nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:

Ok I think I've settled on a solution. Atmega328p as master connected to RF module (SPI) and Atmega1284p (also via SPI). 1284p is connected to the 8/16 matrix and leds. Whole thing powered by li-on battery with charge controller. Charge controller can be plugged into usb to charge battery. usb data lines go to 328P. This solves the need to deal with multiple power sources.

The 328p can detect if usb vbus is connected by checking d- since it is pulled up to vbus, and vbus is isolated by a diode so the battery can't power it. Then its a simple matter of if d- is pulled high, usb must be connected, disable radio and send over usb. Else, use radio.

Comment: How many pins exactly do you need for RF, keyboard matrix, and USB? I don't think the popular 40 pins AVR (have 32 I/O) is not enough. Example: ATMega32, ATMega8535, etc. If you really need more pins, digital switching using a three state buffer is better than relay.

Comment: Thanks! A three state buffer array might do the trick.. I do need a lot of pins, 16x8 matrix, 4 wire spi, additional chip enable pin for RF module, IRQ, not to mention leds...

Comment: Another solution is using multi-microcontroller connected via SPI, TTL/RS-485 UART bus, or I2C. The last one is more difficult to be implemented because of master-slave programming. SPI & UART bus are easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Suggest some of these ways:

- Use of Analog Multiplexer like ADG608 or a Bidirectional Switch like CD4016
- Use a keypad Encoder for connecting your keypad like 74C922 and 74C923. it reduce your required pins and easy programming.
- Use a decoder IC to power-up your LED like 74C154. It only needs programming technique to power on all connected LED simultaneously, e.g. refreshing them with at least 20Hz.
- Use Multiple MCU connected via SPI to controlling your whole circuit (It's your last choice).

Use TTL or CMOS digital ics with MCU for reducing required pins and improving performance of your circuit.

Indeed there are different type of sockets for SMD devices that maybe useful for you, if you have trouble with this SMD packages.

Comment: Thanks for that! I hadn't considered there might be keyboard decoder ICs... I found the TCA8424 which might work if I can manage to solder it. I was thinking about using another MCU on SPI, but I'm a little concerned about the cost in time to send reports along the spi, then forward them to usb host, or worse send through SPI to slave MCU, then through RF transciever. I'll have to do some testing though I may be worrying over nothing

Comment: I 've done such configuration with two MCU through SPI. If you're worry about time, it's not a problem. You can handle it perfectly with a good programming skill.

Answer (score 0):

add another microcontroller, interface with spi since u need usart for RF module...u can also use "decay counter 4017" which has 10 input and only 2 pin for output